# MySQL autoincrement starting from particular number after data entry

Tags: php, mysql

I imported a very large file from CSV which did not have any primary key into a MySQL table. In PHPMyadmin I added another column to my table now, to create a primary key with autoincrement. The problem is that it is starting from 1.

I checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14467577/how-to-autoincrement-starting-from-a-certain-number-offset) and found `ALTER TABLE column AUTO_INCREMENT = 1000;` which will reset the autoincrement again to start from 1000, but is it possible to create an autoincrement from a particular number like 3456 for MySQL after creation of table and data entry?

Comment: What about `ALTER TABLE column AUTO_INCREMENT = 3456;` ??

Comment: So replacing `1000` to `3456` is over your experience?

Comment: Altering autoincrement after creation of table and AI column will affect the rows added after this, I was asking if it was possible
1. After I have added the rows without AI (importing of data)
2. Adding AI starting from a number to already added rows in 1 since it did not had AI in table. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can do so:

```
UPDATE table SET column = column + 3456;
```

Comment: No, this will set the value of column to column + 3456 and has nothing to do with the auto_increment value.

Comment: It seems people are right this is not a AI problem but numbering problem. I added another column with PK and AI and allowed it to start at 1. Later `UPDATE table SET column = column + 3456` did the trick followed by `ALTER TABLE column AUTO_INCREMENT = MAXIMUM NUMBER NOW` . Thankyou everyone and sorry for wrong phrasing of question ;-(